# Straightforward method to get related items view from Solr

Tags: blocks, search, views

I have a Drupal 6 site with an Apache Solr search index.
I'm trying to create a block that displays 'related content', much like Stack Exchange sites have 'related' in the sidebar of questions.
The modules [Apachesolr_views](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_views) seems like a good candidate, but it's current development status and issue queue is less than inviting.
Does anyone have suggestions of a straightforward way to implement this?

Comment: if coding is an option on your end, why not add a `hook_apachesolr_update_index` to add a new index term for related contents' node id based on your related nodes logic (ex. sharing same taxonomy term or having same author etc.) and in your search results fetch the same if necessary with `hook_apachesolr_modify_query` with custom logic to show node title and teaser or whatever the display demands using the node's id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature is actually built in to apachesolr.module. It is called 'mlt' (short for More Like This).

You can add differently configured MLT blocks via `?q=admin/settings/apachesolr/mlt/add_block` and then configure their visibility in `?q=admin/build/block` or whatever block visibility mechanism you are using (context etc).

Comment: Nice! It never ceases to amaze me how Drupal developers spend weeks/months writing modules that do incredible things and then don't write a single character of documentation about it on the project page or readme file.

Comment: Yes but it disappeared in the latest version